How can I resolve CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) errors in my NestJS API?
I have a mistake in a project on Nest JS deployed on EC2 with Nginx, when i make a call from an external frontend to the API the API returns CORS error.
Im checked docs, blogs, tutorial and dont work still. How i can fix this error?
I tried with "origin": "*" and "origin": domain",
This is my configuration on main.ts
import { NestFactory } from "@nestjs/core";
import { AppModule } from "./app.module";
import { ValidationPipe } from "@nestjs/common";
import * as cookieParser from "cookie-parser";

async function bootstrap() {
  // somewhere in your initialization file
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);

  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe({ whitelist: true }));
  app.use(cookieParser());

  const otherAllowedHeaders = ["Authorization", "X-Requested-With"];

  app.enableCors({
    //  "origin": "*",
    origin: "https://my_domain.com",
    allowedHeaders: [
      "Content-Type",
      "Origin",
      "X-Requested-With",
      "Accept",
      "Authorization",
    ],
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    preflightContinue: false,
    optionsSuccessStatus: 204,
  });

  await app.listen(3000);
}
bootstrap();

The nginx.conf
location / {

        if ($request_method = POST) {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
        }
        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            return 208;
        }

        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_pass_request_headers      on;
}

This is the error

